# Download and unpack zip from nexus using Ant and mavent ant task

Tags: ant, maven-ant-tasks

I have a project where I need to download a set of zip files from our nexus and unpack them.
I have the dependency and settings file set up and working but how do I get the files to my local directory so they can be unpacked?

/J

Answer (score 0):

Found a way:
Create a copy task like:

```
    <copy  toDir="./dependencies/">
        <fileset refId="local_build_deps" />
    </copy>
```

Only problem it copies more than I want but at least I get the files I need.
Anyone with a better solution is welcome to respond.

/J